# MongoDB perl driver : different result after aggregation

Tags: perl, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection 'books':

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54901b078b823f2014080700"),
"title" : "title1",
"available" : 0,
"time" : 14318789245,
"score" : 1,
"categories" : ["fiction","humor"]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54901b078b823f2014080701"),
"title" : "title2",
"available" : 1,
"time" : 14318789745,
"score" : 1,
"score_fiction": 5,
"categories" : ["fiction",]
}
...
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54901b078b823f2014080751"),
"title" : "titleN",
"available" : 1,
"time" : 14318789545,
"score" : 4,
"score_fiction": 2,
}
```

I will aggregate it with this script:

```
my $books = $mango->db('test')->collection('books')->aggregate([
  {'$match' => {categories => fiction}},
  {'$project' => 
    {
    'av' => {'$cmp' => ['$available', 0] },
    title => 1,
    scr => {'$ifNull' => ['$score_fiction' , '$score'] },
    time =>1}
    },
{'$sort' => {av => -1, scr => -1, time => -1}},
{'$limit' => 10}
]);

while (my $book = $books->next) {
    print $book->{title} . " [" . $book->{scr} . "]\n";
```

After 5-7 runs I get two different results:

- With sorting by required fields.
- Without sorting. (possibly with sorting by time or the "$natural"
  time of addition).

When I run this aggregation pipeline in mongo's shell - it works with correctly sorting.

```
db.books.aggregate([{'$match' : {categories : 'fiction'},
    {'$project' : {'av' : {'$cmp' : ['$available', 0] },
    title : 1,
    scr : {'$ifNull' : ['$score_fiction' , '$score'] },
    time:1}},
    {'$sort' : {av : -1,scr :-1, time : -1}},
    {'$limit': 10}]);
```

Is the problem in the driver or in my head?

PS I tried Mango and official MongoDB driver, but the result is the same.

Comment: Are you actually inserting single-quoted variables like `'$project'`, or is that an artifact of your example?  Because those don't interpolate.

Comment: Yeah. It is single-quoted. It is strings - operators for MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {'$sort' => {av => -1, scr => -1, time => -1}},
>
> This is likely to be the issue if you're on a recent perl that
>   randomizes hash order. The sort clause needs to be an ordered
>   document. See https://metacpan.org/pod/Mango::BSON#bson_doc for how to
>   do that.

(c) from https://github.com/dagolden